# Problema con PIVOT SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando realizar un PIVOT en SQL donde quiero obtener las incidencias de los empleados por día, aquí el detalle es que pueden tener mas de 1 incidencia por día, por ejemplo 4 Horas extras en un mismo día.

Entonce se supone que cuando encuentre alguna incidencia en tal día, debe de aparecer la incidencia en el día correspondiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me debería de aparecer algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A su vez, tengo un detalle en la consulta, ya que cuando aplico el PIVOT solo obtengo una sola incidencia, y en la siguiente imagen se ven varías incidencias de un empleado en distintos días

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         emp.codigoempleado AS codEmpleado 
        , emp.nombrelargo AS nombreEmpleado
        , FORMAT(detIncidencia.fecha, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS fechaIncidencia
        , COUNT (catIncidencia.idtipoincidencia) AS totalabreviatura2 
FROM tabla1 AS emp
INNER JOIN tabla2 AS detIncidencia ON emp.idempleado = detIncidencia.idempleado
INNER JOIN tabla3 AS catIncidencia ON detIncidencia.idtipoincidencia = catIncidencia.idtipoincidencia
INNER JOIN nom10002 AS periodo ON detIncidencia.idperiodo = periodo.idperiodo

WHERE detIncidencia.semana = 50

GROUP BY 
        emp.idempleado 
        , emp.nombrelargo
        , emp.codigoempleado
        , catIncidencia.idtipoincidencia
        , catIncidencia.descripcion
        , catIncidencia.mnemonico
        , detIncidencia.fecha
        , detIncidencia.idperiodo
        , periodo.ejercicio 
        , periodo.mes
        , periodo.fechainicio
        , periodo.fechafin 
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(SUM(total) FOR fechaIncidencia IN([2019/12/09],
                                                         [2019/12/10],
                                                         [2019/12/11],
                                                         [2019/12/12],
                                                         [2019/12/13],
                                                         [2019/12/14],
                                                         [2019/12/15]
                                                         )) AS nTable;
```

Por ultimo, hay alguna posibilidad de crear las columnas de las fechas dinamicamente, (tengo una función con la que obtengo todos los días entre 2 rangos de fechas pero me muestra un error al querer meterla en el IN() del PIVOT ).
Aquí la columna que harán o deberían de hacer que coincidan, es la fecha de la incidencia

```
DECLARE @desde DATE
DECLARE @hasta DATE

SELECT @desde = (
SELECT 
        FORMAT(fechainicio, 'yyyy/MM/dd') 
        FROM  nom10002
WHERE idperiodo = 48

), @hasta = (
SELECT 
        FORMAT(periodo.fechafin, 'yyyy/MM/dd') 
        FROM nom10002 AS periodo 
WHERE idperiodo = 48
);

WITH 
    CantDias AS (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @desde, @hasta) Cantidad),
    Numeros AS(
        SELECT 1 numero
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n.numero + 1 numero
          FROM Numeros n, CantDias c 
        WHERE n.numero<=c.Cantidad
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Numeros.numero-1, @desde) FROM Numeros OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias diferencias en la información que plasmas y en la que muestras en el pivot.

El detalle de la consulta, en la imagen muestra 5 columnas, pero en la query, que corresponde con el alias source solo hay 4.

Como no pones el origen, voy a simularlo.

```
create table ejem
             (
             codEmpleado       int
           , nombreEmpleado    varchar(100)
           , FechaIncidencia   varchar(30)
           , Incidencia        varchar (100)
           , totalAbreviatura2 int
             );
go

insert into ejem(codEmpleado
               , nombreEmpleado
               , Incidencia 
               , FechaIncidencia
               , totalAbreviatura2)
values
       ( 3853, 'Castillo Morales Juan', 'Accidente de trabajo', '2019-12-09', 1 ),
       ( 3853, 'Castillo Morales Juan', 'Accidente de trabajo', '2019-12-10', 1 ),
       ( 3853, 'Castillo Morales Juan', 'Accidente de trabajo', '2019-12-11', 1 ),
       ( 3996, 'Olivera Olguin Ruben', 'Enf. Gral/Acc Fuera trab', '2019-12-09', 1 ),
       ( 3996, 'Olivera Olguin Ruben', 'Enf. Gral/Acc Fuera trab', '2019-12-10', 1 ),
       ( 3996, 'Olivera Olguin Ruben', 'Enf. Gral/Acc Fuera trab', '2019-12-11', 1 ),
       ( 3996, 'Olivera Olguin Ruben', 'Enf. Gral/Acc Fuera trab', '2019-12-12', 1 ),
       ( 3996, 'Olivera Olguin Ruben', 'Enf. Gral/Acc Fuera trab', '2019-12-13', 1 );
go
```

Están las 5 columnas que muestras en el detalle, con los mismos datos, que salen en la imagen. Algo superimportante es el formato de la fecha. He cogido el de la imagen, porque para trabajarlo en el pivote, es un texto, que tiene que ser igual. Si el formato o separadores son diferentes, no se quejará, pero te devolverá resultados null, como te ocurre a ti.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        * from ejem 
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(SUM(totalabreviatura2) FOR fechaIncidencia IN([2019-12-09],
                                                                     [2019-12-10],
                                                                     [2019-12-11],
                                                                     [2019-12-12],
                                                                     [2019-12-13],
                                                                     [2019-12-14],
                                                                     [2019-12-15]
                                                         )) AS nTable;
```

[image: Resultado]

Por tanto si cambias el select * ejem por tu detalle, y devuelves las columnas en el formato de la imagen, el pivot es correcto.

En cuanto a la segunda pregunta, voy a dividirla en partes.

Muestras un algoritmo recursivo en base a tablas de expresión común, para calcular las fechas, y mezclar eso con pivot, no te dará buenos resultados.

La asignación de fechas que realizas, es más óptima en una sola select.

```
SELECT @desde = FORMAT(fechainicio, 'yyyy/MM/dd') 
     , @hasta = FORMAT(periodo.fechafin, 'yyyy/MM/dd' 
        FROM nom10002 AS periodo 
WHERE idperiodo = 48;
```

Pero si trabajas con campos date, no es necesario utilizar Format, ya que solo igualas valores de la tabla a una variable, para utilizarlas más tarde en otra parte como valores, para una función de fecha. Por tanto la misma asignación debe de ser:

```
SELECT @desde = periodo.fechainicio
     , @hasta = periodo.fechafin
        FROM nom10002 AS periodo 
WHERE idperiodo = 48;
```

Para calcular la diferencia de fechas, puedes utilizar una función tipo tabla, tal que:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tblFechas (@desde date, @hasta date)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
(WITH R1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) TBL(N)
    ), R2 AS (
    SELECT R1.* FROM R1 CROSS JOIN R1 AS R
    ), R3 AS (
    SELECT R2.* FROM R2 CROSS JOIN R2 AS R
    ), R4 AS (
    SELECT R3.* FROM R3 CROSS JOIN R3 AS R
    ), R5 AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROW FROM R4
    ), DESP AS (
        SELECT TOP((DATEDIFF(DAY,@DESDE,@HASTA))+1) ROW FROM R5
        )

    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,D.ROW-1, @desde) AS Fecha
    FROM DESP D
    );
GO
```

Su utilización puede ser algo así.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, FECHADESDE DATE, FECHAHASTA DATE)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID, FECHADESDE, FECHAHASTA)
VALUES
(1,'01/01/2019','10/01/2019'),
(2,'20190101','20190110'),
(3,'2019-01-01','2019-01-10');

SELECT * FROM @TABLE T
CROSS APPLY dbo.tblFechas(t.FechaDesde,t.FechaHasta) fn
WHERE T.ID = 1;
```

[image: Resultado]

Observa que en la variable de tabla, he metido las fechas en diferentes formatos, y funciona exactamente igual. Un campo tipo DATE se almacena en binario, y se explota con formato, por tanto cuando estas mezclando datos, o utilizando funciones, no tienes que formatearlo. Esto se realiza a la entrada, para indicarle al motor que lo que le pasamos es el 10 de enero y no el 1 de octubre, y por supuesto a la salida, para visualizarlos como queremos.

Y por último incluir esto como pivot dinámico. 
Pero tiene su complejidad, y además puede tener un coste importante, no sólo en procesamiento, sino en visualización. Si esto depende de fechas que puede manejar un usuario y no se le da límite, la consulta que se genere, puede ser problemática.

Te recomiendo mirar un poco el tema antes de hacerlo, y a partir de esto, volver a preguntar más explicitamente.

[Pivot dinámico. Cómo hacerlo y entenderlo](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)